# SQL Create Index on View with SUM() in Select

Tags: sql, view, indexing

Using SQL2005, I need to create a view to display the select statement as follows:

```
select c1.personid, Max(c1.call_Date) Call_Date, Sum(s1.quantity) Num_Boxes,
from dbo.kits_dropped s1
inner join dbo.calls c1 on(c1.callsid = s1.callsid)
Where s1.product_name = 'Product X'
GRoup by c1.personid
```

How can I create an index on the personID in the above view?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2615617/1176601 probably applies to your question..

Answer (score 5):

Here's a guide on creating [indexed views in SQL 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx).

This might get you started, this shows a view with a clustered index on `personid`:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 

SELECT 
        c1.personid, 
        MAX(c1.call_Date) AS Call_Date, 
        SUM(s1.quantity) AS Num_Boxes,
FROM dbo.kits_dropped s1
INNER JOIN dbo.calls c1 ON (c1.callsid = s1.callsid)
WHERE s1.product_name = 'Product X'
GROUP BY c1.personid

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyViewInd ON MyView(personid)
```

Please comment if you encounter any issues with the above.

Comment: Ahh, indexed views don't like MAX. To work around this, you could check out [the solution proposed by Adam Haines in this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/c93e0e03-f99d-4659-a1f1-9fd04c9a4130/) and modify `kits_dropped` if possible with a `bit` column, and set the value to `1` for the most recent (MAX) `Call_Date` record.

Comment: `If GROUP BY is present, the VIEW definition must contain COUNT_BIG(*)`, as per the manual page you've linked in your post.